# Firebase Android ML Kit: Way to hide display values on QR code

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

I am using **Firebase** **ML Kit** for Qr code scanning. I have implemented it successfully and its working fine. Now I just need to find a way if there is, to hide the Information (url, ids, display values etc) shown on the image of Qr code.
Below is an image where url can be seen

[image]

Comment: It depends on your implementation. Can you share code, or maybe reference what you used to get the result you have on the screenshot ?

Comment: I have used Google's [Quick Start](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android). And the result is above screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library lets you do whatever you like: show the url on screen or just have in code and process it differently. Normally, you have Bitmap object of image and give it to Barcode Recognizer class and it gives you String value:

```
FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
```

[More Detailed Instructions here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes)

The screen you showed, is just google's implementation, where code is written to show the read value. They draw white rectangle and url in class `BarcodeGraphic`, you can comment URL part and it will not be drawn:
[image]

Comment: Sometimes thinks are too much simple than we think. Thanks a lot man.